# spaCy: what is NORM-part of tokenizer_exceptions?

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize, spacy

I'm adding `tokenizer_exceptions` for my language. I was looking at `'gonna'` example for English language, so wrote the rule as follows:

```
'т.п.': [
    {ORTH: "т.", NORM: "тому", LEMMA: "тот"},
    {ORTH: "п.", NORM: "подобное", LEMMA: "подобный"}
],
```

Then when I tokenize, I expect that `NORM`-parts of rule will be in `token.norm_` (though there is no any documentation about `Token.norm_`). But instead I see `ORTH`-part in `token.norm_` and nowhere in the `token`-instance I could see the `NORM`-part of rule.

So what is `Token.norm_`-member and what is `NORM`-part of `tokenizer_exceptions`-rule for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer the question more generally: In spaCy v1.x, the `NORM` is mostly used to supply a "normalised" form of a token, for example the full inflected form if the token text is "incomplete" (like in the `gonna` example), or an alternate spelling. The main purpose of the norm in v1.x is making it accessible as the `.norm_` attribute for future reference.

However, in v2.x, [currently in alpha](https://alpha.spacy.io/docs/usage/v2), the `NORM` attribute becomes more relevant, as it's also used as a feature in the model. This lets you normalise words with different spellings to one common spelling and ensures that those words receive similar representations – even if one of them is less frequent in your training data. Examples of this are American vs. British spelling in English, or the currency symbols, which are all normalised to `$`. To make this easier, v2.0 introduces a new language data component, the [norm exceptions](https://alpha.spacy.io/docs/usage/adding-languages#norm-exceptions).

If you're working on your own language models, I'd definitely recommend checking out v2.0 alpha (which is pretty close to a first release candidate now).

Comment: OK tnx. Understood.

Comment: So, if `NORM` attribute is a some kind of synonym (which obviously isn't, strictly speaking), then for `'gonna'` example `NORM` attribute is redundant in v 1.x, right? :)

Comment: @AlexMedveshchek In v1.x, the `NORM` isn't used in the model, but setting it in the tokenizer exceptions can still be valuable to provide information that's not covered by the other attributes. In many cases, the normalised form is identical with the lemma and thus redundant – e.g. `[{ORTH: 'ca', LEMMA: 'can'}, {ORTH: "n't", LEMMA: 'not'}]`. However, in the "gonna" example, the first token looks like this: `{ORTH: 'gon', LEMMA: 'go', NORM: 'going'}` – without the `NORM`, you wouldn't be able to get across that "gonna" == "going to".

Comment: Thanks. I agree: NORM-attribute could be really useful in many cases, and for me it's obviously that for "gonna" - it's vital attribute.

But my concern was that I don't see the value of `NORM`-attribute anywhere in `Token` instance after tokenizing the text.

In other words, when I've tokenized text "gonna" with English tokenizer, the value of `token[0].norm_` doesn't equal to "going", but == "gon" (i.e. `ORTH`). And no any member in `token[0]` contains value of "going". So where's the "going" gone? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can bind any function in `nlp.vocab.lex_attr_getters`, and it will be computed for that vocabulary entry. Each token holds a pointer to its vocabulary item, so they will all reference this computed value.

```
import spacy
from spacy.attrs import NORM

nlp = spacy.blank('ru') # In spacy 1, just spacy.load() here.

doc = nlp(u'a a b c b')

[(w.norm_, w.text) for w in doc]
# (a, a), (a, a), (b, b), (c, c), (b, b)

nlp.vocab.lex_attr_getters[NORM] = lambda string: string.upper()
# This part should be done automatically, but isn't yet.
for lexeme in nlp.vocab:
    lexeme.norm_ = nlp.vocab.lex_attr_getters[NORM](lexeme.orth_)
[(w.norm_, w.text) for w in doc]
# (a, A), (a, A), (b, B), (c, C), (b, B)
```

You can bind these lexical attributes to anything you want. I'm not sure how the binding works for Russian, but you can either change it in the source, or just at run-time by resetting the lexical attribute function.

Comment: You mean that I could to set a `token.norm_` attribute via setting it in vocab additionally? E.g., when loading vocab or in `__init__()` method of my Language class?

I just didn't understand your example with `lex_attr_getters` - what kind of problems could it cover, since you wrote in python-comment, that this part doesn't work automatically?